# Transition Audiostream between two Endpoints

Tags: windows, winapi, audio

I'd like to transfer a running third party audiostream from one endpoint to another via Windows Core Audio API. Is that possible? And if, where is that documented? I already searched the documentation, but didn't find anything.

Windows itself can do that: If you change the default device, all running streams transition from the old device to the new device. Now I'm hoping that there is an API or an Interface for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, some day someone will find this: There is no such functionality in the Windows OS, which is exposed by an API as of today.